# Finding which key value pair is equal to X in a JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript

I am sorting through a database but essentially just working with a javascript object. Inside this object i have variables and i need to find the lowest variable. I have done this but to do it i have to find the values which is the number not the name of the key value pair that the value is equal to, how could i find which value is responsible for the lowest result?

Here is the database object:

```
        {
            cave: cave,
            environment: {
                activity: activity,
                recovery: recovery,
                psychology: psychology
            },
            variable: {
                training: training,
                mobility: mobility,
                sleep: sleep,
                nutrition: nutrition,
                stress: stress,
                motivation: motivation
            },
            date: moment().format('ll'),
            user: Meteor.user().username
        }
```

So, im going into this and finding the lowest of all the variables using this:

```
Math.min(
         findVariable(0, 'training'),
         findVariable(0, 'mobility'),
         findVariable(0, 'sleep'),
         findVariable(0, 'nutrition'),
         findVariable(0, 'stress'),
         findVariable(0, 'motivation')
        )
```

and findVariable is this:

```
findVariable = function(dayOffset, findValue){
    var log = dailyLog.find({user: Meteor.user().username, date: findDate(dayOffset)}).fetch()[0];

    return log.variable[findValue];

};
```

So i find the values of each variable which is an integer value, but i dont want to display the number i want to display the variable nameHow can i get the variable name responsible for the smallest value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be to [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) over your `variables`:

```
var variables = {
  training: 1,
  mobility: 4,
  sleep: 6,
  stress: 5
};

var lowestVariable = Object.keys(variables).reduce(function (lowest, variable) {
  if (variables[variable] < variables[lowest]) {
    return variable;
  } else {
    return lowest;
  }
});

// training
```

This way you wouldn't need to do a a `dailyLog.find` for every variable name, instead you could just look the log once, and then reduce over the `variable` property:

```
findLowest = function (dayOffset) {
  var log = dailyLog.find({user: Meteor.user().username, date: findDate(dayOffset)}).fetch()[0];

  return Object.keys(log.variable).reduce(function (lowest, variable) {
      if (log.variables[variable] < log.variables[lowest]) {
        return variable;
      } else {
        return lowest;
      }
  });
}
```

Comment: It works a charm, reversed it for the highest variable also and works perfectly. I am bloody confused though! How does the reduce function work, does it go through each variable and each time return the lowest one and if not smaller it return the original? Thanks so much though man works perfectly!